# Установка Ubuntu(черный экран без курсора)

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-10, dual-boot

Хочу установить Ubuntu 16.04 на свой Lenovo IdeaPad Z585 второй ОС вместе с Windows 10. Создал загрузочную USB при помощи Rufus, при попытке установить Ubuntu, после выбора пункту *install Ubuntu* или любого другого пункта меню, имею черный экран, убирается он только перезагрузкой.
Пробовал ставить и другие сборки: Debian, Manjaro, Mint.
Записывал при помощи Unebootin, rufus, universal-usb-installer.
Результат всегда один и тот же. При этом на других машинах( домашний пк и ноутбук товарища) все работает корректно. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: а Live-вариант загружается с флешки? на чёрном экране вообще ни на что не реагирует? `Escape`?  `Alt+F2 .. Alt+F6`?

Comment: Live не загружается, не реагирует ни на что. Esc в меню выбора переносит в grub-консоль, после выбора установки или теста диска или лайв режима не реагирует на Esc. По поводу Alt+F2 & Alt+F6 сейчас попробую.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала обновить bios на lenovo.com

Comment: Скорее всего проблема с UEFI. Попробуйте покопать в этом направлении: https://habrahabr.ru/post/259283/ или http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/uefiboot

Comment: На Alt+F2 и Alt+F6 не реагирует, сейчас изучу данные материалы, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Подозреваю, имелись в виду `Ctrl+Alt+Fx` для переключения tty

Comment: Помог комментарий пользователя vp_arth - обновление bios решило проблему.

Comment: а если такая же тема на virtualbox? все равно в биос лезть?